# Why is it sufficient to consider positive functions in the proof of Theorem 4.2 in Markov Processes by Ethier and Kurtz?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, martingales, markov-process

I read the proof of Theorem 4.2 in Markov Processes in Ethier and Kurtz (Chapter 4, pages 184-186) , and I have a question in one detail in the proof that I cannot explain. The theorem essentially states that if any two solutions to a martingale problem have the same one-dimensional distributions, then they have the same finite dimensional distributions.

[image]

In the part of the proof where uniqueness is proved, it is said that it is sufficient to consider positive functions. Why is that? Are the positive bounded functions on a metric space separating? and why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f_k=f_k^{(0)}-f_k^{(1)}$, where $f_k^{(0)}(x)=\max\{f_k(x),0\}$ and $f_k^{(1)}(x)=\max\{0,-f_k(x)\}$. Suppose that we proved (4.19) in the case where the functions $f_k$ are non-negative. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E^{P}\left[\prod_{k=1}^m f_k(X(t_k))\right]&=\mathbb E^{P}\left[\prod_{k=1}^m \left(f_k^{(0)}(X(t_k))-f_k^{(1)}(X(t_k))\right)\right]\\
&=\sum_{\delta_1,\dots,\delta_m\in \{0,1\}}(-1)^{\sum_{\ell=1}^m\delta_\ell}\mathbb E^{P}\left[\prod_{k=1}^mf_k^{(\delta_k)}(X(t_k))    \right]\\
&=\sum_{\delta_1,\dots,\delta_m\in \{0,1\}}(-1)^{\sum_{\ell=1}^m\delta_\ell}\mathbb E^{Q}\left[\prod_{k=1}^mf_k^{(\delta_k)}(X(t_k))    \right] \mbox{ by (4.19) for non-negative functions}\\
&=\mathbb E^{Q}\left[\prod_{k=1}^m f_k(X(t_k))\right].
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. Just a quick question - should it be $\sum_{k=1}^{m} \delta_k$ instead of $\delta_k$ in the exponent of $-1$?

Comment: @Eran You are right, I fixed it. Thanks.